# L2tp protocol security

Tags: encryption, openvpn

do l2tp protocol is secure enough to use in unsafe home network ?
protection from man in the middle ?

i having a problems install openvpn in linux
you think following that guide will offer me security in unsafe home network ?
https://support.hidemyass.com/hc/en-us/articles/202721556-L2TP-Setup-on-Fedora

l2tp 128bit [ MPEE],[MSCHAP + MSCHAPv2]